# How to add a gesture recognizer to a shape drawn by uibezierpath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am drawing a circle in the drawRect function in a subclass of UIView

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width/3, self.bounds.size.height/2, 200.0, 200.0));

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);
}
```

I want to add a gesture recognizer to the circle to make it tappable

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

I thought of dragging a UIGestureRecognizer onto the view (in storyboard) in the location where the big circle will be, but the circle is much bigger than the UIGestureRecognizer widget.

How can I either combine the code or assign a UIGestureRecognizer to an area of the view that's exactly the same as the size and location of the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it using drawRect the way you are, but I've done something similar using UIBezierPath. I subclassed UIView, and made this view the main view of my controller. This is the code in that view,

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

     if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
         self.shape = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width/3, self.bounds.size.height/3, 200.0, 200.0))];
        }
     return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [self.shape fill];
}
```

shape is a property declared in the .h file. In the view controller .m file, I add the gesture recognizer, and check if the touch is inside the shape,

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) RDView *mainView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mainView = (RDView *)self.view;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}

-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) tapper {
    if ([self.mainView.shape containsPoint:[tapper locationInView:self.mainView]]) {
        NSLog(@"tapped");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, What type is "self.shape" in the .h file?

Comment: @Leahcim, "@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath *shape;

Comment: Thanks, should have known that about UIBezierPath :)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't. Gesture recognizers are attached to views, not shapes or layers. You would have to create a custom view object for each shape. You could certainly do that.

What I suggest you do is to create a custom subclass of UIView that manages all your shapes. (I'll call  it ShapesView) Have that custom ShapesView manage an array of custom shape objects. Attach a gesture recognizer to your ShapesView. In the code that responds to gestures, have it do custom hit testing to determine which shape was tapped, and move the shapes around.

UIBezierPath includes a containsPoint method that would allow you to do hit testing if you maintained a bezier path for each shape.

Comment: Thanks, I only need one circle that responds to a gesture.